# Additive simulation via ANSYS APDL (PYANSYS/MAPDL)

Tags: python, ansys, ansys-apdl

I have attempted to simulate additive manufacturing using ANSYS APDL. I have already applied an element type of SOLID278 with relevant material properties for aluminum 7075. I have also used 'Mapped Meshing' due to my design parameters. In addition to this, I have used the 'Element Birth and Death Technique' with a 'DO* LOOP' to simulate the additive manufacturing of 'Laser Cladding'. However, after running my PYANSYS code, I am running into this error where physical gaps are visible once the simulation is complete (shown in the image below). I would appreciate the solution to this cause.

I have done the simulation for a small section of my model and it works fine. However, the full simulation includes this error of missing elements.

[image: Model including visible error]

The following code below is my code used for the full process in ANSYS APDL:

```
    !----------------!Pre-processing----------------

/PREP7 
!* 
ET,1,SOLID70     !Thermal 3D element

!----------------!Defining Material Properties----------------

!* 
/UNIT,SI 
MPTEMP,,,,,,,,  
MPTEMP,1,0  
MPDATA,EX,1,,71.7e09
MPDATA,PRXY,1,,0.32 
MPTEMP,,,,,,,,  
MPTEMP,1,0  
MPDATA,KXX,1,,130   
MPTEMP,,,,,,,,  
MPTEMP,1,0  
MPDATA,C,1,,960 
MPTEMP,,,,,,,,  
MPTEMP,1,0  
MPDATA,DENS,1,,2810 

!----------------!Geometry----------------

/PREP7  
K, ,0,0,0,                  !Modelling with Keypoints to create geometry
K, ,0.004,0,0,  
K, ,0.005,0,0,  
K, ,0.005,0,0.002,  
K, ,0.004,0,0.002,  
K, ,0,0,0.002,
   
K, ,0,0.004,0,  
K, ,0.004,0.004,0,  
K, ,0.005,0.004,0,  
K, ,0.005,0.004,0.002,  
K, ,0.004,0.004,0.002,  
K, ,0,0.004,0.002,  

K, ,0,0.005,0,  
K, ,0.004,0.005,0,  
K, ,0.005,0.005,0,  
K, ,0.005,0.005,0.002,  
K, ,0.004,0.005,0.002,  
K, ,0,0.005,0.002,  
!*
CYL4,0.005,0.005,0.0005, , , ,0.002  !Create Cyclinder
lplot   
KL,7,0.5, ,   
KL,2,0.5, , 
!*
/REPLO                                                                      !Create Volumes from Keypoints
V,       1,       2,       5,       6,       7,       8,      11,      12   
V,       2,       3,       4,       5,       8,       9,      10,      11   
V,       7,       8,      11,      12,      13,      14,      17,      18   
V,      14,      21,      25,      17,       8,      28,      27,      11   
V,       8,      28,      27,      11,       9,      19,      26,      10   
!*
FLST,2,2,6,ORDE,2                                                           !Substract Cyclinder from Main Volume
FITEM,2,5   
FITEM,2,-6  
VSBV,P51X,       1  

!----------------!Optimised Mesh (Mesh Size 0.4mm)----------------

lplot   
FLST,5,41,4,ORDE,10 
FITEM,5,9   
FITEM,5,11  
FITEM,5,-40 
FITEM,5,42  
FITEM,5,-43 
FITEM,5,45  
FITEM,5,47  
FITEM,5,-48 
FITEM,5,50  
FITEM,5,-54 
CM,_Y,LINE  
LSEL, , , ,P51X 
CM,_Y1,LINE 
CMSEL,,_Y   
!*  
LESIZE,_Y1,0.0004, , , , , , ,1 
!*  

!----------------!Creating the Mesh (0.4mm)---------------- 

FLST,5,5,6,ORDE,4   
FITEM,5,2   
FITEM,5,-4  
FITEM,5,7   
FITEM,5,-8  
CM,_Y,VOLU  
VSEL, , , ,P51X 
CM,_Y1,VOLU 
CHKMSH,'VOLU'   
CMSEL,S,_Y  
!*  
!*  
VCLEAR,_Y1  
VMESH,_Y1   
!*  
CMDELE,_Y   
CMDELE,_Y1  
CMDELE,_Y2  
!*  

!----------------!Solutions-Settings----------------

/SOL
TUNIF,293,           !Uniform temperature
TREF,293,            !Reference temperature
KBC,0               !Ramped loading
NEQIT,100           !No. of iteration

!*                                                                                           
ANTYPE,4                                                                                      !Define model Transient Analysis
!*  
TRNOPT,FULL                                                                                   !Define Solution Method
LUMPM,0                                                                                       !Use of 'Lumped Mass approx.'
!*         
NROPT,FULL                                                                                    !Specify Newton-Raphson as Full Transient Analysis
TIME,1                                                                                        !End of Time Step

!----------------!Kill all ELEMENTS---------------- 

!*  
FLST,5,114,1,ORDE,2                                                                           !Select all NODES
FITEM,5,1   
FITEM,5,-114
NSEL,S, , ,P51X 
ESLN,S                                                                                        !Select all ELEMENTS attached to those NODES
/GRAPHICS,FULL                                                                                !Turn Off POWERGRAPHICS
EKILL,ALL                                                                                     !Deactivate all ELEMENTS
ESEL,S,LIVE                                                                                   !To confirm success of EKILL command: Select all 'Live ELEMENTS'
/REPLO

!----------------!DO LOOP COMMAND----------------

*set,user_time,0

!*do,variable_z,0,0.002,0.001
!*do,variable_y,0,0.005,0.0012
*do,variable_x,0,0.0012,0.0012


NSEL,S,LOC,X,1*variable_x,0.0012+variable_x
NSEL,R,LOC,Y,1*variable_y,0.0012+variable_y
NSEL,R,LOC,Z,1*variable_z,*0.001+variable_z

ESLN,S
EALIVE,ALL                                                                                    !Re-Activate Selected NODES
SFE,ALL, ,HFLUX, ,10e05
!DELTIM,0.1,0,0              !Time step size, 0.1 s
user_time=user_time+1
TIME,user_time              !Total time, 1 s
AllSEL,ALL
SOLVE
SFEDELE,all,all,all            !Removing surface element load
/GRAPIHCS,POWER                                                                               !Turn On POWERGRAPHICS
esel,s,live
eplot
*enddo
!*enddo
!*enddo
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you, Friedrich. I have updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In the input file these lines indicate that all the nodes are to be selected.  But the `'picker'` style input is only selecting 114 of the 1248 nodes in the model.  So here:

```
!----------------!Kill all ELEMENTS---------------- 

!*  
FLST,5,114,1,ORDE,2                                                                           !Select all NODES
FITEM,5,1   
FITEM,5,-114
NSEL,S, , ,P51X
```

Instead of selecting elements based on some node picking, why not just select *all* elements and kill them:

```
esel,all
ekill,all
```